# Multiple facets and Label coloring/ordering in Heatmap (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, heatmap, facet

For a research paper on nuclear waste issues, I am trying to make a heatmap of "**Attributes**" (in X) versus "**Models**" (in Y) with some discrete values being given (in Z, coloring) for each (X,Y) couples. I do all this for different "**Scenarios**".

My **dataset** looks like this:

```
head(tspa)
                 ï..Scenarios            Components
1 Total System (10,000 years) Unsaturated Zone Flow
2 Total System (10,000 years) Unsaturated Zone Flow
3 Total System (10,000 years) Unsaturated Zone Flow
4 Total System (10,000 years) Unsaturated Zone Flow
5 Total System (10,000 years) Unsaturated Zone Flow
6 Total System (10,000 years)       EBS Environment
                              Models WTYPE WCOMP WRAD WPROP WTREAT WFORM
1                 Site-Scale UZ Flow     0     0    0     0      0     0
2              Infiltration Analysis     0     0    0     0      0     0
3                   Climate Analysis     0     0    0     0      0     0
4                      Drift Seepage     0     0    0     0      0     0
5            Drift Wall Condensation     0     0    0     0      0     0
6 EBS Thermal-Hydrologic Environment     0     0    0     0      0     1
  WPACKAGE STRUCT OVERPACK ROCK GEOPHYS GEOCHEM HYDRO BIO SEISM VOLCA
1        0      0        0    1       0       0     1   0     0     0
2        0      0        0    1       0       0     1   0     0     0
3        0      0        0    0       0       0     0   0     0     0
4        0      1        0    1       0       0     1   0     0     0
5        0      1        0    0       0       0     1   0     0     0
6        1      1        0    0       1       0     1   0     0     0
  CLIMA HUMAN
1     0     0
2     0     0
3     1     0
4     0     0
5     0     0
6     0     0
```

Notes on data:

- The full dataset can be found here: [tspa.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ahuqsix9dpfn2b8/tspa3.csv?dl=0)
- Labels in CAPITAL letters correspond to the Attributes, the rest
  should be explicit.
- The "ï.." character is added to the first cell "Scenarios" when
  importing the csv database into R (using R Studio). I have no idea
  where this error is coming from (encoding of my CSV file?)?
  Ideally, this should be simply "Scenarios".

And here is my **"working" script** at the moment:

```
# Heatmap 2

# Load dependancies
library(tidyr)       # consistent data.frame cleaning
library(ggplot2)     # base plots are for Coursera professors
library(gridExtra)   # a helper for arranging individual ggplot objects
library(ggthemes)    # has a clean theme for ggplot2

# Read data and format for heatmap
tspa <- read.csv(file="tspa3.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
tspa.long <- gather(data = tspa, key = Attributes.name, value = Attributes.value, -c(1:3))

gg <- ggplot(data = tspa.long, mapping = aes(x = factor(Attributes.name, levels = unique(Attributes.name)),
                                                     y = factor(Models, levels = unique(Models)),
                                                   fill = Attributes.value), stat="identity")
gg <- gg + facet_wrap(~ ï..Scenarios , ncol=6)
gg <- gg + geom_tile(color="grey", size=0.1)
gg <- gg + coord_equal()
gg <- gg + scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(tspa.long$Models)))
gg <- gg + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL, title=NULL)
gg <- gg + theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0))
gg <- gg + theme(axis.ticks=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(axis.text=element_text(size=7))
gg <- gg + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position = "none")
gg <- gg + scale_fill_gradient2(low="white", high=muted("red"), limits=range(tspa.long$Attributes.value))

gg
```

This script generates the following heatmap with a faceting per Scenario only: [**Result**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njc4v.png)

[image]

However, even after extensively searching about the topic and trying [various approaches](https://www.biostars.org/p/205417/) (ggplot2, superheat, heatmaply, pheatmap...), I remain unable to plot exactly what I need.

Here is what I struggle with:

1. In addition to the faceting of Scenarios, **how to facet (group) the Attributes (X, by Categories) and Models (Y, by Components) that are all hierarchically organized?** (my dataset links "Models to Components" and I have another data file linking "Attributes to Categories") -- On faceting, I tried [this](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/223-faceting-with-ggplot2/), [this](https://rud.is/b/2016/02/14/making-faceted-heatmaps-with-ggplot2/) and [that](https://jcoliver.github.io/learn-r/006-heatmaps.html).
2. Inside each facet (Attributes, Models, and Scenarios), **how to keep the order of the labels as shown in my data file** and not in alphabetical order? -- At the moment, only the Attributes are correctly ordered, but not Models and Scenarios.
3. **Is it possible to highlight or change the color of the labels of X and Y for a given value Z?**

Since I am fairly new to R, and data visualization in general, I am still having limited understanding of how the R code exactly works. I suspect that I may have to use various dataframes or use IF/THEN loops but I don't know how to do this.

I am OK with having general guidance about what architecture and functions to use for my dataset and script that I can figure out myself later. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't ever include `rm(list = ls())` in code you share on stack overflow (I edited it out). If anyone runs your code to reproduce your problem and try to help you, this would wipe their entire environment (extremely frustrating if they'd just imported a big dataset or spent hours running simulations)

Comment: OK, noted! Thank you.

Comment: @François: for your 1st and 2nd questions, this might help http://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html

Comment: @François: for the 3rd one, you can use a simple `ifelse` statement to code the color you want. There should be plenty of examples on SO if you search. Or you can use this package https://github.com/yutannihilation/gghighlight

Comment: @Tung Wonderful. I'll look into that and let you know if that worked.